# Xamarin Forms - Best practice to load JSON from RestAPI

Tags: json, sqlite, rest, api, xamarin.forms

I am looking for best practices for loading JSON into my Xamarin.Forms application.

The JSON contains data for the six to eight views of the app. I can format the JSON to be either a single file, containing all information (much more than 10 000 lines), or to contain only the information needed for the specific view.

In detail my questions are whether:

- I should send a single request, obtaining all data, and store the business objects in a sqlite-net database. I would then call the database whenever it is needed and modify the objects in the view model.
- or send multiple requests, obtaining only the data needed for the view. This data would not be stored in a database I guess.

To provide a bit more Information about the application, the views are used for monitoring data and navigating deeper into the application means getting more detailed information.

I am looking forward for your suggestions.

Comment: If you are used for monitoring data and need detailed information, I think send multiple requests is prefer.You can keep the data to the latest like a news application.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks for your answer. In Future, the app should also have a show/hide feature. Am I right by thinking that in this case, a database with an additionally column with a bool value is useful?

Comment: Yes, it could be useful

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thanks. I will try this approach then.

Comment: You are welcome. Can I post above comment to answer, and you mark it, it will help others who have similar issue?

Comment: Yeah, go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are used for monitoring data and need detailed information, I think send multiple requests is prefer.

You can keep the data to the latest like a news application.

And you can use a database with an additionally column with a bool value.